# A stamp board using a DB

Tags: android, database

I'm going to make a stamp board. If I enter a specific password, it will be stamped in a specific area corresponding to that password. I think this app. need a DB to remember that a certain area has been stamped. I think I can choose Internal Storage or Shared Preference to implement this function. Which is easier and suitable for the features I want to create?

Comment: I know that SQLite is used to save things like a save file of a game. So I don't think it's suitable for the function I'm trying to make, so take it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think according to your need the mysql will be the best choice because generally, shared preference in used to store small value like username, passwords or some constants.Whereas the sql is a proper database with queries to help you get data from your stomp board.

One more database is realm database which is based of sql only and is much better and faster.hope it helps

Comment: Is mysql difficult?

Comment: no not at all.You can get the mandatory database files for android from net and then create your own database table to use it

Comment: check the answer again i have edited